# Azure Anycast for application

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am porting a website to Microsoft Azure. But our clients are scattered throughout the world, so my intention is to deliver our website as fast as possible to our customers in the US as we do in Germany or China. So I was thinking about something like a CDN on application level for our PHP/Ubuntu-Environment.

I know, there is a CDN implementation for static pages in Microsoft Azure, but I do not have any idea as how to achieve this on the application level.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about deploying on each continent and use Traffic Manager performance mode to direct the clients to the nearest data center?

Comment: If this wasn't a comment, I would have marked it as right answer. Thank you. Exactly, what I need.